# jQuery animate function

Tags: jquery

Good afternoon lads,

I've been working on a jQuery over function which allows you to highlight a div a preview div.

URL's:

```
<a class="hoverlogo" href="/cms-logo-'.$row['id'].'">Logo</a>
<div id="preview-logo"></div>
```

jQuery below:

```
$("a.hoverlogo").hover(
function() {
    $("#preview-logo").animate({backgroundColor: '#cccccc'});
},
function() {
    $("#preview-logo").animate({backgroundColor: '#fff'});
});
```

But when i keep doing mouseover a several times the animation wont stop highlighting.
How-to stop the animations when I'm not on the a href URL anymore?

Thanks for your time,

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

may be this: http://jsfiddle.net/Z8FsU/1

```
$("a.hoverlogo").hover(
    function() {
        $("#preview-logo").stop()
                          .animate({
            backgroundColor: '#cccccc'
        });
    }, function() {
        $("#preview-logo").stop()
                          .animate({
            backgroundColor: '#fff'
        });
    }
);
```

.stop() - stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.